# If the graphs of $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ intersect at an odd number of points, is at least one point on the line $y=x$?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, inverse-function

I was reading about intersection points of $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ in this site. ([Proof: if the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=f^{-1}(x)$ intersect, they do so on the line $y=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336098/proof-if-the-graphs-of-y-fx-and-y-f-1x-intersect-they-do-so-on-the)) 
Then, I saw this statement was wrote by N. S.: "If the graphs of $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ intersect at a **single** point, then that point lies on the line $y=x$.

It is also true that if the graphs of $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ intersect at an odd number of  points, then at least a point point lies on the line $y=x$. This follows immediately from the observation that the intersection points are symmetric with respect to that line..." 
I want to know whether it's true or not and if it's true how we can prove it algebraically?

My try: I tried many function and this statement was true but I can't prove it. (Or disprove.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is mainly a counting argument involving just a little algebra on the functions themselves.

The functions $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ intersect either at a finite number of points, or an infinite number of points.
If the number of intersections is infinite, it is neither odd nor even.
So we only need to consider a finite number of intersections.

If $(p,q)$ is one of the intersection points, that means
$q = f(p) = f^{-1}(p).$
But from $q=f(p)$ we can deduce that $f^{-1}(q) = p,$
and from $q = f^{-1}(p)$ we can deduce that $f(q) = p,$
therefore $p = f(q) = f^{-1}(q),$ that is,
and the two functions also intersect at $(q,p).$

So consider the set of intersection points that are above the line $y=x.$
Suppose there are $n$ of these points, where $n \geq 0.$
For each point $(p,q)$ above the line $y=x$
(that is, where $q>p$), there is a corresponding point $(q,p)$ below the line $y=x,$ and vice versa.
Hence there are $n$ points below the line $y=x.$

Let the number of intersection points *on* the line $y=x$ be $m.$
Then the total number of intersection points is $n$ above the line, $n$ below the line, and $m$ on the line (where $m\geq 0$), for a total of
$$
2n + m.
$$
Now, $m$ has the same parity as $2n+m.$ 
If the total number of intersections $2n+m$ is odd, 
it follows that $m$ is odd.
But zero is not odd; all non-negative odd numbers are positive.
So the total number of intersections on the line $y=x$ in that case
is an odd positive number.
In particular, it is at least $1.$

In this proof, we never assume there are any intersection points above the line $y=x,$ nor that there are any below the line or on the line.
But we show that *if* there are an odd number of intersection points altogether, the number of intersection points on the line is positive.

Comment: Your proof is wonderful! But what about even intersection points ? What we can say about it ?

Comment: I think if number of intersection points is even , all of the points lie on the $y=x$ line. For example $f(x) = \sqrt x$ and then $f^{-1}(x) = x^2$ , $x \ge 0$ . Therefore intersection points are $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

Comment: Try $f(1)=2, f(3)=0,$ and for all $x$ other than $0$ and $3,$ $f(x)=x-1.$ The intersection points are $(1,2)$ and $(2,1).$ If you restrict $f$ to continuous functions, however, I think it may only be possible to have a decreasing function with an odd number of intersections or an increasing function with all intersections on the line $y=x.$

Comment: Okay consider continuous functions  . Can you provide a function that number of intersection points with inverse is even and at least one of the points isn't locate on $y=x$ ?

Comment: If my thoughts about continuous functions are correct, the only choices are an odd number of intersections or all intersections on $y=x,$ so the answer would be no. I just don't have a complete proof in mind yet. (To be precise, I'm thinking about continuous functions on connected domains; if you allow a disconnected domain I think it may be possible to have an even number of intersections and none of them on $y=x.$)

Comment: Okay , thank you a lot for your answers . Great!