# Solve for $x,y$ and $z$ when: $x+y=\sqrt{4z-1}, \ y+z=\sqrt{4x-1}\ \mathrm{and} \ z+x=\sqrt{4y-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to Solve for $x,y$ and $z$ when: $x+y=\sqrt{4z-1}, \ y+z=\sqrt{4x-1}\ \mathrm{and} \ z+x=\sqrt{4y-1}$.

I've added the equations and get: $2(x+y+z)=\sqrt{4x-1}+\sqrt{4y-1}+\sqrt{4z-1}$ and after this how I proceed further?

Even if I subtract the first two equations then I'm getting:
\begin{align*}
x-z&=\sqrt{4z-1}-\sqrt{4x-1}\\
\Rightarrow\left(x+\sqrt{4x-1}\right)^2&=\left(z+\sqrt{4z-1}\right)^2\\
\Rightarrow\left(x^2-z^2\right)+4(x-z)&=2z\sqrt{4z-1}-2x\sqrt{4x-1}
\end{align*}
after this also I can't understand how to help with this.

Comment: Two of your three equations are identical.  Is there a typo?

Comment: Not a general approach, but you could observe by graphing that there is a unique solution, and try setting $x=y=z$: then $2x = \sqrt{4x - 1}$ i.e. $4x^2 = 4x - 1$ i.e. $4x^2 - 4x + 1 = 0$ i.e. $4(x - 1/2)^2 = 0$. So $x=1/2$, and, indeed, the solution $x=y=z=1/2$ works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $\;x,y,z \ge \frac{1}{4}$ for the square roots to be defined. Assume WLOG that $x \ge y \ge z\,$, then $\sqrt{4z-1}=x+y \ge z+z = 2z \implies 4z-1 \ge 4z^2\iff (2z-1)^2 \le 0 \,$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $x,y,z$ are real numbers such that
\begin{align*}
x + y &= \sqrt{4z-1}\\[4pt]
y + z &= \sqrt{4x-1}\\[4pt]
z + x &= \sqrt{4y-1}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Let $s = x + y + z$. Since $x + y \ge 0,\;\;y + z \ge 0,\;\;z + x \ge 0$, we have $s \ge 0$.

Then from the original system of equations, we get

\begin{align*}
(s-z)^2 &= 4z-1\\[4pt]
(s-x)^2 &= 4x-1\\[4pt]
(s-y)^2 &= 4y-1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Let $f(u) = (s - u)^2 - (4u - 1) = u^2 - (2s + 4)u  + (s^2+1)$.

Then, $x,y,z$ are roots of $f$, hence, since $f$ is quadratic in $u$, at least two of $x,y,z$ must be equal.

Without loss of generality, assume $z = y$.

Suppose $x \ne y$. Then since $x,y$ are roots of $f$, Vieta's formulas yield

\begin{align*}
&x + y = 2s + 4\\[4pt]
&xy = s^2 +1\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

hence, since $s \ge 0$, we get $x,y > 0$. Then also $z > 0$, since $z=y$. But then

\begin{align*}
&x,y,z > 0\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x + y < s\\[4pt]
\implies\; &2s + 4 < s\\[4pt]
\implies\; &s < -4\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

contradiction.

It follows that $x = y$, hence $x = y = z$, so

\begin{align*}
&(s - z)^2 = 4x-1\\[4pt]
\implies\; &(2x)^2 = 4x -1\\[4pt]
\implies\; &(2x-1)^2 = 0\\[4pt]
\implies\ &x = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\\[4pt]
\implies\; &x = y = z = {\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

It's easily verfied that the triple

$$
(x,y,z) = 
{\small{
\left(
\frac{1}{2},
\frac{1}{2},
\frac{1}{2}
\right)
}}
$$

satisfies the original system of equations, hence it's the only solution.

Comment: @maverick -- thanks for the edits

Answer (score 2):

If there is a solution, the symmetry of the equations suggests we investigate the possibility that $x=y=z$

So assume that $x=y=z=a$.

$$2a=\sqrt{4a-1}$$

Thus $4a^2-4a+1=0$, or $(2a-1)^2=0$. Thus $x=y=z=\frac{1}{2}$.

This is a solution. But, as per the comment of dxiv below, this does not rule out solutions where $x\ne y$, $y\ne x$, $z\ne x$.

Comment: `Since your equations are symmetric ...` I think that requires some elaboration, since it's not necessarily true in general. Consider for example the system $x+y^2=1, y+x^2=1\,$.

Comment: @dxiv I see your point. I will edit my "answer."

Comment: Thanks. Checking out the "symmetric" solutions is still a useful heuristic, and it can suggest substitutions or monotonicity arguments to further chase down other solutions, or prove that none other exist. However, discerning upfront whether the symmetric solutions are the only ones is not straightforward, not even in the simple case of just $2$ variables, which was my point. Somewhat related: [Proof: if the graphs of $y=f(x)$ and $y=f^{-1}(x)$ intersect, they do so on the line $y=x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/336313) (emphasis on the linked answer, not the title of the question).